# Expanding / Collapsing divs

Tags: php, jquery

I have multiple expanding / collapsing boxes on a single page being generated by PHP / MySQL.

Problem is, when I click on one link to expand a box, it expands all the boxes.

I thought about appending the post ID at the end of the class (`<div class="postreplycontainer-POST_ID">`) but I am not sure if that will work since I'd have to figure out a way to change the jQuery.

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Draven/kUhkP/35/

Keep in mind, I can't manually code in each box because I am pulling the content from the database.

**EDIT:** Maybe somebody can help me with an additional problem.

I want to focus the `textarea` box when I expand the `<div>`. I tried using the same trick as before (using `.closest` but that didn't work).

Here's the example: http://jsfiddle.net/Draven/kUhkP/53/

This example will always focus the first `<textarea>`.

Comment: Thank you everyone that answered! They all worked but I chose the answer that didn't rely on any table following the div.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vonDy2791/kUhkP/40/)**

```
$("a.postreply").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.blog-container')
        .find('.postreplycontainer').slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call `$("div.postreplycontainer")` you will access all divs, if the div is always after a table you can use

```
$("a.postreply").click(function() {
    $(this).parents('table').next().slideToggle("fast");
});
```

to slide that div http://jsfiddle.net/kUhkP/39/

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be ok for your problem.

```
$("a.postreply").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('.blog-table').next().slideToggle("fast");
});
```