# Expand div+focus, collapse previous divs, and auto-expand on new page

Tags: jquery

I am looking to do a few things things:

1. Focus `<textarea>` when expanding a `<div>` box.
2. Collapse previous open `<div>` boxes when expanding a new one
3. When clicking the "Edit" link the text goes into the `<textarea>` to be edited. So I either need a way to use jQuery to put the string into the `<textarea>` or auto-expand the `<div>` to show the `<textarea>` with the string inside it to edit it.

I have expanding / collapsing working thanks to a previous question of mine: [Expanding / Collapsing divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17291737/expanding-collapsing-divs)

The content is being generated by PHP / MySQL.

Here's my Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Draven/kUhkP/85/

Sorry if I left out any important information, I'll edit this post if I think of something I should add.

**More on #3**

When clicking the "Edit" link the page "refreshes" (it's the same page but the URL changes) and the content they want to edit is now displayed in the `<textarea>` box. When the page changes it displays the page with all `<div>` boxes collapsed.

I need the `<div>` with the editable content that's in the `<textarea>` to be expanded automatically.

Is there a way to check if a `<textarea>` has content then have that `<div>` expanded?

Comment: answer updated and working correctly (despite the negativity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/xtGgd/1/):

```
$(document).on('click', '.postreply', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('.blogcontainer').siblings('.blogcontainer').find('.postreplycontainer').slideUp("fast");
    $(this).closest('.blogcontainer').find('.postreplycontainer').slideToggle("fast")
        .find('textarea[name=replycontents]').focus();
});
```

Here I use `$(document).on` in order to `delegate` an event to **ALL** elements, both present and future (dynamic).  Keep in mind, if you're ever using jQuery *pre*1.7 then you'll simply change `.on` to `.delegate`. Since it is delegating, `.delegate` seemed appropriate at one time, however, times have changed. Now, you can still use '.delegat' if you want. jQuery has made note that they have not "deprecated" nor do they intend to remove `.delegate`. They simply feel the implementation of `.on` in 1.7 superseded `.delegate`, thus they recommend to use `.on` for delegating.

All that hosh posh aside, using the delegate form of `.on` is quite simple, as you can see. The rules are simple. The `$(selector)` should either be a "parent" element that is "present onload" or you can just simply use `$(document)`.

Your `.on` params are just as easy. First parameter is a string name of the `event` you want assign ed. Keep in mind, you can assign multiple events with just a space; exp `'change keydown'` (this is popular events assignment for textareas).

The second parameter is like any other jQuery selector. Just keep in mind, **ALL** elements that meet the requirements will be assigned. So something like `'div'` would assign an event to ALL div elements.

The last is the "callback" method. The `e` of course represents the `event Object` that is passed in. For instance `e.target` would be the same in the function as `$(this)`

---

As for ***#3***

If you're reloading the page every time, then simply find the first text area with content and dropping down its parent container. This just means adding one simple line of code:

```
$('.blogcontainer textarea[name=replycontents]').filter(function(i) { return $.trim($(this).val()) != ""; }).closest('.postreplycontainer').slideDown("fast");
```

To break this down some:

- `$('.blogcontainer textarea[name=replycontents]')`: I think you understand selectors by now, but just a note, remember, you can use "*any*" CSS selector as a jQuery selector.
- `.filter(function(i) { return $.trim($(this).val()) != ""; })`: this handy little jQuery method allows us to "filter" the results of our "Selection" based on a given callback.

  - The `(i)` stands for *index* and is 0 based.
  - The return method I use here "*trims*" the **value** of a textarea, thus removing trailing and leading white space. 
    -Thus a textarea meant to be edited that has nothing but whitespace will return false. 
    -You may need to edit this return to suite your needs.
  - Read more: http://api.jquery.com/filter/
- `.closest('.postreplycontainer')`: Simply grab closest parent element matching the selector.

  - Why do we want parent now? Well we found the textarea with content, now we need to expand the parent.
  - Keep in mind, while multiple textareas may have content, as soon as we add this to the chain, we are getting only the parent of the FIRST one with conent
- `.slideDown("fast");`: finally,. close the chain by sliding down the box with content!

See [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xtGgd/3/)! Keep in mind, I dont "reload" the page or anything. But by having the line there, the first box with content will always slide down. If that's not desired, you may want to look into using [jQuery's Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) in order to edit a box.

Comment: `$('.replycontents').focus();` will always focus on the first one

Comment: @AtifMohammedAmeenuddin and? isn't that what he wants?

Comment: No, he wants the textarea inside the respective `.blogcontainer` to get focus.

Comment: @AtifMohammedAmeenuddin ok, so you found one small prob, negd me, and yet your answer still isnt right ... silly children

Comment: It's not negative. Works good. Thank you. I still have the third problem to solve. I should have made that a separate question.

Comment: @Draven yea, just annoyed with atif, anywho, come bak in a minute, i'll have answer updated with more info on each part maybe help you understand it a bit better. Despite my nub rep, I been manipulating jQuery for years

Comment: Very cool man. Good explanation. I did notice in the JSFiddle that you used the original `$("a.postreply").click(function () {` though. Would it be safer for me to change that to `$(document).on`?

Comment: if you're expecting "dynamic" links, then yes, but as you mentioned, you're reloading the whole page, thus it may not matter. But if you start using ajax to add blog content panels, then yes. Adding #3 answer now

Comment: I have a feeling Ajax may be the only way to get #3 working. If it'll help I'll create a public page (instead of JSFiddle) with what I am working on.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32412/discussion-between-draven-and-bilbob533)

Comment: The solution to #3 isn't perfect but I think I can get it work. You've been extremely helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @bilbob533 I did not neg rate you dear. I just didn't vote. And now you have my +1 vote. Why taking so personally?

Comment: @AtifMohammedAmeenuddin sorry it appeared that way, as for personal, because i had another acount for a long time that only answered stuff. The first 5 questions i finally asked, i got negged right out of my account and saw nothing but negativity for well formulated questions seeking reasonable answers. I've just become easily aggravated lately.

Comment: losing a 10K+ account will do that to ya i guess

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a.postreply").click(function () {
    $('.postreplycontainer').hide();
    $(this).closest('.blogcontainer').find('.postreplycontainer').slideToggle("fast");
    //$('.replycontents').blur();
    $(this).closest('.blogcontainer').find('.replycontents').focus();
});
```

Takes care of 1 and 2. I didn't understand the 3rd point.

Comment: Looks good except you can't collapse the expanded `<div>` when clicking "Post Reply" a second time.

Comment: I just edited my question to give more information on problem #3